# How to create a string array in the useState hook and update that same array in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a React project where I am trying to create a multi select function where you can select and deselect multiple avatars at once.

So far I have this:

```
export interface IStoreRecommendationProps {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  discountNumber: number;
  discountItem: string;
  arr: string[];
  onClickAvatar: () => void; // pass a specific parameter for avatar
}

export const StoreRecommendation: React.FC<IStoreRecommendationProps> = ({
  title,
  description,
  discountNumber,
  discountItem,
  arr,

  onClickAvatar,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState({
    arr[],
  });
  const showIcon = (id) => {
    arr.push(id);
    console.log(arr);
    setVisible(id);
    onClickAvatar();
  };

  const displayContacts = () =>
    CUSTOMERS.map((person) => (
      <AvatarContainer>
        <Avatar
          picture={{uri: person.profile_picture}}
          onPress={() => showIcon(person.customer_id)}
        />
        <TextAvatar>{person.name}</TextAvatar>
        {visible.includes(person.customer_id) && <CheckIcon />}
      </AvatarContainer>
    ));
```

In the showIcon() I am trying to save an array of IDs in the state and update them accordingly(push if clicked, remove if clicked again) and then just check the array in displayContacts() by doing visible.includes(person.customer_id)

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState({
    arr[],
  });
  const showIcon = (id) => {
    arr.push(id);
    console.log(arr);
    setVisible(id);
    onClickAvatar();
  };
```

```
const displayContacts = () =>
    CUSTOMERS.map((person) => (
      <AvatarContainer>
        <Avatar
          picture={{uri: person.profile_picture}}
          onPress={() => showIcon(person.customer_id)}
        />
        <TextAvatar>{person.name}</TextAvatar>
        {visible.includes(person.customer_id) && <CheckIcon />}
      </AvatarContainer>
    ));
```

I am grabbing customers from a seperate file and it looks like this:

```
export const CUSTOMERS = [
  {
    customer_id: '1',
    name: "John Doe",
    profile_picture: "https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/portrait-white-man-isolated_53876-40306.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
    approval_status: false,
    payment_method: Enums.OrderPaymentMethod.IN_PERSON
  },
  {
    customer_id: '2',
    name: "Evan Green",
    profile_picture: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/portrait-concept-picture-id1016761216?k=6&m=1016761216&s=612x612&w=0&h=j-DyZTSqmnhoHKsJdGmiMPnungpHiq9UTrvx4UylMQI=",
    approval_status: false,
    payment_method: Enums.OrderPaymentMethod.IN_PERSON
  },
  {
    customer_id: '3',
    name: "Grace Lewis",
    profile_picture: "https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/friendly-brunette-looking-camera_23-2147774849.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
    approval_status: false,
    payment_method: Enums.OrderPaymentMethod.IN_PERSON
  }, ...]
```

Now when I try to do visible.includes() I get an error where it tells me my array is of type never. Am I doing the array initialization to the useState() hook wrong, and am I on the right track to do what I am attempting to do?

Comment: `arr.push(id);` looks to be mutating that passed `arr` prop. Don't mutate state or props in React. Also, `setVisible(id);` will wipe out any existing state array and replace it with `id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following, solves the issue (hopefully :)):

1. Replace

`const [visible, setVisible] = useState({ arr[],});` with

`const [visible, setVisible] = useState<string[]>([]);`

for proper initialisation and type definition

2. Replace

   ```
   const showIcon = (id) => {
        arr.push(id); 
        console.log(arr);
        setVisible(id);
        onClickAvatar();
      };
   ```

with

```
     const showIcon = (id) => {
         setVisible(prevState => {
         // check if it is already added
         if(prevState.includes(id)) { 
           // clone the prevState arr to prevent side effects  
            const clone = [...prevState];
          // Remove the existing id 
            clone.splice(prevState.indexOf(id), 1)
            return clone;
         } else {
            return [...prevState, id]
         }});
         onClickAvatar();
     };
```

Note: `arr` is not relevant here as it is not used elsewhere and is redundant so it should be removed

Comment: Thie behaves in such a way that when I click on an avatar twice, it deselects every single one except for the selected one. 


Expected behaviour is that whenever I press on an avatar the second time, it deselects.

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you try again?

Comment: Works amazingly, can you edit your solution to clarify what you did with clone just for people who view this in the future? What was the need for clone? Also I will approve this as the answer.

Comment: Nice. Thanks, @IbrahimNoorMohammed. I just update the answer. We clone the prevState array with the ...(spread operator) just to make our solution more cleaner/prevent unintended bugs.

Comment: @IbrahimNoorMohammed `array.splice` does an in-place mutation so you need to shallow copy the array into a new array reference. You could `.slice` it first, or more typically you just `.filter` the previous state to the next state, i.e. `return prevState.filter(el => el !==id);`.

Comment: Thank you @DrewReese, this is the more efficient solution. The .filter method is exactly what the splice and clone is trying to do but more efficiently.

Comment: can use a map instead.  React.useState<{[key: string]: string}>({});

Answer (score 0):

You mean to be initializing `visible` as an array and then interacting w/ that array via `setVisible`, rather than a direct manipulation method.
Try something like this:

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState([]);

  const showIcon = (id) => {
    setVisible([...visible, id])
    console.log(visible);
    onClickAvatar();
  };
```

assuming your initial state of visible is an array of ids like `[34, 63, 12]` and you call `showIcon(20)`, it should update `visible` and log out to `[34, 63, 12, 20]`

Comment: I suggest using functional updates, `setVisible(visible => [...visible, id])` so state updates from previous state and not the state closed over in callback scope, and the console log will only log the current state, not what it will update to for the next render.

Comment: The same problem occurs where visible in setVisible([...visible, id]) is of type never when it needs to be string.

Edit: if you look above, the customers array that I grab the data from has id as a string value from 1 incrementally so that is what I am trying to pass as the ID

Comment: When I use the functional update, I'm getting: `Argument of type '(visible: never[]) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type '(visible: never[]) => any[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: never[]) => never[]'.
    Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
      Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)`

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out by forcing the type like this: `const [visible, setVisible] = useState<Array<string>>([]);` 

It works now for adding it to the array, however how would I get a second click to remove it from the array?

Comment: perhaps something like this?:  

`const removeFromVisible = (idToRemove) => {
  setVisible( visible => visible.filter(id => id !== idToRemove) )
}`

Answer (score 0):

I was blocked and I tried everything... solution ?

The comment from **Drew Reese**

> I suggest using functional updates, setVisible(visible => [...visible, id]) so state updates from previous state and not the state closed over in callback scope, and the console log will only log the current state, not what it will update to for the next render.

Just using this gave me bad result :

```
setVisible([...visible, id])
```

But perfect with :

```
setVisible(visible => [...visible, id])
```

A big thanks !